# onKeyUp is not calling in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need to get the character whenever there is a change in the text on change in multi select dropdown.

But onKeyUp is not firing. Please find the below code for reference...

```
const options = [
    { label: "option 1", value: 1 },
    { label: "option 2", value: 2 },
    { label: "option 3", value: 3 },
    { label: "option 4", value: 4 }
  ];
  const onKeyUp= e => {

      alert(e.target.getAttribute("value"));

  };
  const onKeyDown = e => {

      //alert(e.target.getAttribute("value"));

  };
  const selectedOption =value=>{
    alert(value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={options} onKeyUp={onKeyUp}  onKeyDown={onKeyDown} onChange={selectedOption} />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check `react-select`'s [documentation](https://react-select.com/props), you will notice that there's no `onKeyDown` props available.

You should consider adopting something like:

```js
class App extends Component {
  onKeyUp = () => {
    // your code here ...
    console.log("your code here");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp} className="App">
        <Select options={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Example available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/onkeyup-props-react-select-clcr1).